# Is There a Bluetooth File Transfer Application

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, transfer

Does Ubuntu have an application that can transfer files over Bluetooth?
I can pair my desktop with my MacBook, and the Mac has an application it calls BT FileTransfer but when I run this, the Mac reports that my desktop does not accept that sort of connection.
I did install the obexfs and obexftp packages but I am uncertain how to use them.
pgmer6809

Answer (score 1):

Install Blueman. Once installed, right click on the Blueman icon in the notification area and select Local Services . . . , click on Transfer. Select your *Incoming Folder* (where you want transferred files to arrive). Make sure *Accept files from trusted devices* is checked.
[image: Local Services]

Here is a complete manual on how to use Blueman: [archlinux manual on Blueman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Blueman#Can't_receive_files)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't see a Local Services item on my Blueman, but using Blueman I am able to send a file from the MacBook to my Linux box. When I try it the other way, the progress bar goes to completion then I get a box with, "Error Occurred. Could not find service record." There is no indication on the MacBook that anything is trying to contact it. This might be a MacBook problem, I am not sure. Anyway half way there thanks. I will try Linux to Linux next.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Bluetooth.
2. Click on Bluetooth to open the panel.
3. In the Devices list, select the device to which to send the files.
4. Click Send Files… and the file chooser will appear.

[image: send files dialog]

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-send-file.html.en